# how to trigger user-pilot(user on-boarding software) trigger function on click of a button in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using user-pilot for nice user on-boarding experience. It's available in js script format.No npm package available for it .
My problem is I want to trigger it from my react component on click of a button. User-pilot create a following script.
({userpilot.trigger("156405494dRzh9302")})
how can  I trigger it from the click of a button which is inside the react component.Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `userpilot` is available globally, you can just do this:

```
<button onClick={() => userpilot.trigger("156405494dRzh9302")}>click me!</button>
```

Comment: Thanks! it's working by adding window.userpilot.trigger("156405494dRzh9302")}